# Is there a way to programmatically get the Redshift total data scanned metric for a query run via Redshift data API?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, amazon-cloudwatch

My team has a Lambda that triggers various queries that runs from our Redshift cluster.

I can evaluate the query in the console by selecting a query execution, and it shows various metrics, but in particular I'm interested in the "total data scanned" for reporting purposes:
[image]

We already have some metrics being emitted per query type from my Lambda based on the response from [Describe Statement](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift-data/latest/APIReference/API_DescribeStatement.html) of the Redshift Data API, but it only gives back the "result rows" and "result size", and not the information about the data scanned. While those pieces are also useful, we need to track total data scanned as well since it will help us with troubleshooting.

Is there a similar way to get this data scanned information programmatically? It looks like there might be a table we can query for the information, but I was hoping we could get the data directly from the API somehow.

Comment: do you have an XY problem ?

Comment: @MitchWheat - I don't believe I do, but feel free to clarify why you think I do

Comment: well, you want to  measure the amount of data read. Why? is it to reduce costs, is it because you have slow queries? what's the root problem?

Comment: We aren’t necessarily aiming to reduce the data read - rather, we want to be able to easily visualize when there are drastic changes in the size of the data we are querying for specific queries we are running (per query). The root problem is that yes, sometimes our queries are slower, but oftentimes it is for other reasons and we would like to be able to pinpoint if incoming data is the reason.